# Python Popen input from variable?

Tags: python, popen

I am trying to use Popen to run a java program that takes a few arguments, the last of them is a xml template.

What I have so far attempts to pass the value of the template through communicate(), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
command = [
        'java',
        '-jar',
        '~/jenkins-cli.jar',
        '-noKeyAuth',
        '-s',
        'docker-host',
        'create-job',
        (self.project.project_name+'-'+env)
    ]

subprocess.Popen(command,
                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE
                 ).communicate(input=template.render(template_vars))
```

I know for a fact that the value of template.render(template_vars) is correct, I can use the output from that function call on the command line and it works perfectly, the issue is only in passing the value to the process.

If I run the following from the command line everything works.

```
java -jar ~/jenkins-cli.jar -noKeyAuth -s jenkins-host create-job test-dev < template.xml
```

Is there a better way to send the output of template.render(template_vars) as input to the process?

Comment: "the last of them is an xml template" doesn't seem to be true; it seems like that XML template is the stdin of the Java program, not a command-line argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your problem is the input here, but rather the arguments. In particular:

```
'~/jenkins-cli.jar',
```

On the command line, you get shell tilde expansion for free. But when using `subprocess` (or calling `exec`-family functions from any language, as `subprocess` does), you have to do it manually, like this:

```
os.path.expanduser('~/jenkins-cli.jar'),
```

Also, you're passing a different value for the `-s` option (`'docker-host'` instead of `'jenkins-host'`), and for the project name (`'something-env'` instead of `'test-dev'`), so the fact that the command line works doesn't really show that your code should work.

---

As a side note, if you're trying to debug your code, ignoring the stdout, stderr, and return code seems pretty silly. Print them out and see what you get, like this:

```
p = Popen(command, …)
out, err = p.communicate(input=…)
print(p.returncode, out, err)
```

Or, of course, don't capture the `stdout` and `stderr` in the first place, so they just print to the console.

Comment: It was ~ that was messing things up for me, thanks I completely missed my use of it.The issue with me saying jenkins-host vs docker-host was a typo on my part, in the actual code it specifies the url for my jenkins master which I was removing, the second time It typed it I just screwed up and typed docker since I've been using it so much. Thanks for the help.